# Making Circular progress bar(or loading bar) in cmd

Tags: cmd

Like this is an example of rectangular box

```
@echo off
color 0A


setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set Counter=10
set Schalter=100
set Width=100

:1
set /a Counter=%Counter% + 1
set /a Display=%Counter% / 2
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,%Display%) DO (
   set Display=!Display!Û
)
cls
echo     Loading...                         %Counter%%%
echo     Û!Display:~2,47!
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
if "%Counter%" == "93" endlocal & goto End
goto 1

:End
cls
```

And if such is this possible in batch to make circular progress bars??
How to make such with circular progress bar......????

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like this ? (based on your code)

```
@echo off
color 0A


setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /A Counter=1 >NUL
set Schalter=100
set /A Width=30>NUL
SET /A Start=1 >NUL
set /A Length=1 >NUL
SET /A Rotate=0 >NUL
SET /A DisplayCount=0 >NUL

:1
SET /A Counter=Counter + 1 >NUL
SET /A DisplayCount=(Counter%%Width) >NUL
IF "!DisplayCount!" == "0" SET /A Rotate=1 - Rotate >NUL
IF "!DisplayCount!!Rotate!" == "00" SET /A Start=1 >NUL
IF "!DisplayCount!!Rotate!" == "00" SET /A Length=1 >NUL
IF "!Rotate!" == "1" SET /A Start=Start + 1 >NUL
IF "!Rotate!" == "0" SET /A Length=Length + 1 >NUL
set "Display=|"
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,!Start!) DO (
   set "Display=!Display! "
)
FOR /L %%A IN (!Start!,1,!Length!) DO (
   set "Display=!Display!X"
)
cls
echo     Loading...                         %Counter%%%
echo     !Display:~2,47!
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
if "%Counter%" == "193" endlocal & goto End
goto 1

:End
cls
```

Are you looking for a kind of progress bar that do ?  :

```
XX
XXX
XXXX
  XXXX
    XXXX
      XXXX
...
X
XX
XXX
XXXX
  XXXX
    XXXX
...
```

Comment: Not working.............
Similar to what i made just showing X instead of progress bar

Comment: Are you looking for a progress bar behaving like showed in the edit ?

Comment: Looking for something like this in cmd.......
http://mio-parliamo.fun/qdbyw/sLT0MHRzBPIo45GaF0thMQHaEq.jpg

Comment: Really ? It's possible, but why do you need that in a console script ?